# Help replicating a simple graph in a textbook

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines = left,
        ]
            \addplot[
                    domain=0:10,
                    color=red
            ]{x^3 - 15*x^2 + 63*x + 165};
            \coordinate (A) at (100,10); 
            \coordinate (B) at (600,50);            
            \draw (A) node[below] {a} node[scale=0.75] {$\bullet$};
            \draw (B) node[below] {b} node[scale=0.75] {$\bullet$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

A LaTeX beginner would appreciate replicating the attached textbook graph as well as the points, arrows, labels, and lines. I'd like to say I haven't been too bad at searching for solutions however my slight OCD wants to replicate it perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

I suppose you want to replicate the first image. If this were the case, the best way (IMHO) is to use plain Ti*k*Z and to declare some functions (the curve, its derivative and possibly the tangent line equation).

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}

\tikzset
{
  every node/.style={black},
  declare function=
  {
       f(\x)=1/3*(\x-0.5)^3-2*(\x-0.5)^2+3*(\x-0.5)+1.5; % function
      df(\x)=(\x-0.5)^2-4*(\x-0.5)+3;                    % derivative
   t(\x,\xo)=df(\xo)*(\x-\xo)+f(\xo);                    % tangent at \xo
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
% some points (x-coordinates)
\def\a{0.5}
\def\b{2.5}
\def\c{4.5}
\def\tp{4.2} % tangent point
%\draw (0,0) grid (5,4);
% area
\fill[red!30] (\a,0) node[below] {\strut$a$} -- (\a,{f(\a)}) --
 plot[domain=\a:\b,samples=51] (\x,{f(\x)})  |- node[below] {\strut$b$} cycle;
% axis
\draw[-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (5,0) node[below] {\strut$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node[left]  {$y$};
% tangent line
\draw (\tp-0.5,{t(\tp-0.5,\tp)}) -- (\tp+0.7,{t(\tp+0.7,\tp)}) coordinate[pos=0.2] (r);
% curve
\draw[red!70!black,thick] plot[domain=\a:\c,samples=101] (\x,{f(\x)});
% point P
\fill (\tp,{f(\tp)}) circle (0.5mm) node[left] {$P$};
% labels
\node at (1,3.2) {$y=f(x)$};
\draw[latex-] (2,2) to[out= 30,in=240] (3,3)   node[above] {area = ?};
\draw[latex-] (r)   to[out=-30,in=120] (4.5,1) node[below] {slope = ?};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=.05]
%\tzhelplines[thick,ystep=1/.05](11,160)
%% axes
\tzaxes(-1,-20)(11,160){$x$}[b]{$y$}[l]
\tzticks{1,2,...,10}{20,40,...,140}
\tzshoworigin
%% f(x)
\def\Fx{(\x)^3-15*(\x)^2+63*\x+20}
\tzfn[thick]\Fx[0:10]
%% area
\tzvXpointat{Fx}{1.5}(A)
\tzvXpointat{Fx}{4.5}(B)
\tzprojx[dashed](A){$a$}
\tzprojx[dashed](B){$b$}
\tzfnarea*[red]\Fx[1.5:4.5] % area
%% tangent
\tzvXpointat*{Fx}{9}(P){$P$}[al]
\tztangent[red]{Fx}(P)[8:10.5]
%% labels
\tznode(1,120){$f(x)=x^3-15x^2+63x+20$}[r]
\tzto[<-,bend left=3](3,80)(5,100){area=?}[r]
\tzto[<-,bend left=1](8.5,80)(9,60){slope=?}[b]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```